# how to show "No record found" in Telerik RadPivotGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using AJAX **RadPivotGrid** to show some data in . But if there are no records, how to show the "No records found" message. I tried different options, but nothing is working. Does any one know how to achieve this?  i know in normal radgrid there are options to show this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Telerik RadPivotGrid but is there an option to edit Template? If so, there should be an EmptyDataTemplate where you put whatever you want to display when no records are returned. You may already know this and that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such template in the control

You can consider using another template and adding something custom if you have no data for the particular item, but I am not sure it will be enough for you http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/pivotgrid-templates.html

Comment: As a work around, i have to create an empty data set and then bind the same to the grid as below 
 var noRecodsList = new List<dynamic>();

                        var obj = new
                        {
                           Name = "No records Found"
                        };
                        noRecodsList.Add(obj);
                        rpGrid.DataSource = noRecodsList;

Comment: You can also set thePivotGrid.Visible=false and show a Label/Literal instead.